# UseApolloClient query won't return fetchMore

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo-hooks

I am working on project with Apollo on client side. I am using react-apollo-hooks on my client side. And I have a problem with useApolloClient.

When i fire query with my client I got in useApolloClient I don't get back all data I need. FetchMore is missing. If I use regular query (useQuery) I get that. But problem is I need to fire that query on click and i need to use one provided with apollo client.

I have this function for fetching data on click:

```
    const bulkSearch = async data => {
        setContent(<Spinner />);
        showModal();

        try {
          const response = await client.query({
            query: BULK_SEARCH_PRODUCTS,
            variables: { data }
          });

          if (!response.loading) {
            setContent(
              <ProductsListDisplay
                products={response.data.bulkSearch.products}
                fetchMore={response.fetchMore}
                count={{ total: 10 }}
              />
            );

            return 200;
          }
        } catch (err) {
          return 400;
        }
      };
```

And response doesn't contain fetchMore.

On the other way classic query returns fetchMore.

```
    const newdata = useQuery(BULK_SEARCH_PRODUCTS, {
        variables: { data: { ids: ["536003", "513010"] } }
      });
```

Some help ? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the `apollo-client` docs, [ApolloClient.query](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client/#ApolloClient.query) returns a Promise that resolves to an [ApolloQueryResult](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client/#ApolloQueryResult), which is a simpler object that has only `data`, `errors`, `loading`, `networkStatus`, and `stale` as properties.

On the other hand, the [render prop argument](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo/#query) of `react-apollo`'s `Query` component gets fed a much richer object, with `fetchMore` being one of its additional properties. If you want to do something similar using the raw ApolloClient object, you would have to use [ApolloClient.watchQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client/#ApolloClient.watchQuery), which returns an [ObservableQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client/#observablequery) that you can [subscribe](https://github.com/zenparsing/zen-observable#observablesubscribeobserver) to consume results. The benefit of this is that you have access to more methods, such as [ObservableQuery.fetchMore](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client/#ObservableQuery.fetchMore).

Note this approach is fundamentally different than using `ApolloClient.query`, since that function requests one query and returns the result as a Promise, while `ApolloClient.watchQuery` consistently monitors your cache and pushes updated results to your subscribe method when the cache store changes, so it's a more complicated lifecycle. In general, if you're already using `react-apollo` or one of the `@apollo/react-X` packages, you probably want to stay away from `ApolloClient.watchQuery`, since the functionality from those libraries builds directly on top of it and is designed to be easier to consume.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thanks for the great answer. I used query component at the end, but I didn't know this, helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own `FetchMore` method for this. This has to be handled by you that's the safer you to go.

In my case I needed

**fetchMore**

- Adding Infinite loading and should event deal with loading state as well.
- Problem with default loading state is that it will be always false as return of promise.

When you use `await client.query`.

---

In our query we have cursor based pagination.

**[read](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/cursor-based/) this**

- Create Function that will trigger on scroll ( end of page )
- Check on value of after and update it with state management
- Loading as well as data also needs to be in state.

Code:

```
const fetchMoreFilteredData = async (after) => {
    try {
        setFilteredLoading(true); // set this state in order to show loading indicator

        const { data, loading } = await client.query({
            query: QUERY,
            variables: {
                after: after,
               ...all variables,
            },
            fetchPolicy: "network-only",
            notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
        });

   const {
     query: {
       pageInfo: { hasNextPage, endCursor },
     },
   } = data;

   setFilteredData({
    // update your data ...filteredData, 
   });

   setHasNextPage(hasNextPage); // check if there is next page
   setEndCursor(endCursor); // set end cursor for next page this will guide the query to fetch next page
   setFilteredLoading(loading); // set loading state to false
 } catch (error) { 
   error.graphQLErrors.map((error) => {
     console.log("error", error.message);
   });
   setFilteredLoading(false);
 }   };

 const handleLoadMore = () => {
   hasNextPage && fetchMoreFilteredData(_endCursor);   
 };
```